# Anchor complains "some crates are on edition 2021 which defaults to...."

Tags: anchor

I have a simple Anchor app, and `anchor test` works, but I see the warning:

```
% anchor test
warning: some crates are on edition 2021 which defaults to `resolver = "2"`, but virtual workspaces default to `resolver = "1"`
note: to keep the current resolver, specify `workspace.resolver = "1"` in the workspace root's manifest
note: to use the edition 2021 resolver, specify `workspace.resolver = "2"` in the workspace root's manifest
```

Got it - I need to update the "workspace root's manifest" but what file is this? And what do the changes look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Posting my own solution to help others.*

Essentially Rust updated, and older projects need their settings changed. [Newer Anchor releases will do this by default](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/pull/2676).

In `Cargo.toml`, set the following items under `[workspace]`:

```
[workspace]
...snip...
resolver = "2"
```